# Mouse not working correctly

Tags: mouse

So for the last month or so on my Ubuntu 13.10, after installing nvidia drivers and then re installing nouveau drivers (because nvidia didn't work correctly) I got a problem with my mouse. I just made fresh install of 14.04 LTS, but problem persists. Problem is:

- Every 3rd or so click my mouse does not register left click.
- Sometimes mouse makes double click when I make just a single left click.
- Often mouse releases and reapplies left click when I am holding left button.

For example when I try `xev | grep ButtonRelease` and click on rectangle, I often get double release output, sometimes even triple. I cannot even select text normally due to this problem, it usually goes like this: [image]

I tried mouse in Windows 8.1 and it works perfectly. I am extremely frustrated because of this problem. I posted about this on Ask Ubuntu several weeks ago with no replies.

**Update**: tested friend's wireless mouse and it works well. So maybe it's a defective mouse, but then why it works in Windows 8.1?

**Update 2:** tested this mouse on friend's ubuntu 12.04 system and it works better, but still same problem happens. Does that mean it's defective mouse for sure?

**Update 3:** I bought new simple Logitech mouse and the problem is solved. Apparently it was defective mouse.

Comment: For reference, the AU question is [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/441146/6969), I'll close that one in favor of this one. Can you reproduce this problem in a Live USB environment?

Comment: Just tested, yes same problem in live ubuntu usb.

Comment: Update: tested friend's wireless mouse and it works well. So maybe it's a defective mouse, but then why it works in Windows 8.1?

Comment: Could be fancy software [debouncing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debouncing#Contact_bounce) in Windows.

Comment: You say it "releases and reapplies left click when holding". Does it do this when you're not moving it? This smells a bit like your system is using the wrong mouse protocol. But if it still happens when you're not moving, then it's not likely.

Comment: Yes it still happens when I am not moving. For example if I do: xev | grep ButtonRelease
and click and just hold, sometimes it releases twice in 2-3 second period.

Comment: This still happens a lot to me as well, sometimes I need to click a button like 10 times before the click is registered. I don't think its a mouse issue since google search turn up endless of people having this issue.

Comment: @Daniel Did you fix the issue? Maybe any updates?

Comment: @user1880405 Nope, though I found one mouse this didn't happen. I tried 4 different mouses. All of which works on Windows. Ubuntu only takes 1/4 mouses.

Comment: @Daniel I see, so you are pretty positive it's not mouse issue but Ubuntu?

Comment: I would *guess* Windows is filtering out (ignoring) very fast clicks. What you're describing is a reasonably common way mouse button hardware fails, so that's probably what happened.