# Wrong number of 'clicks' from mouse & drops click and hold, then picks it up again

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

The issue I am experiencing is the same as the one in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125408/mouse-not-working-correctly/139251#139251).

This is happening on two different machines, using two different models of mice. While both mice are Logitech, one is a wireless 2-button w/scroll wheel and the other is wired 4-button w/trackball. Both machines are running Ubuntu, though the one with the 2-button mouse has 12.04 on it and the one with the 4-button has 14.04.

The big difference between the issue I have and the post I linked, is that his issue started after installing an Nvidia driver.  The 12.04 machine uses and Nvidia driver, the 14.04 doesn't.

The major strangeness is that the mouse behavior began (on both machines) seemingly without change to either system. I have intentionally NOT updated the 12.04 machine for many months now and have not installed any new software on it.

On the 14.04 machine, the behavior began while 12.04 was still on it... I was hoping a distribution upgrade would fix things. No big surprise, it didn't. In fact it is now worse on the 14.04 machine.

I tried adding an xorg.conf file, with configurations to enable 3-button emulation, and while 3-button, trackball scrolling, etc. now work, the click, double click, triple click, and 'dropping' the left click & hold are still present.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Marble Mouse"
    MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
    Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
    Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"
    Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
    Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
EndSection
```

The above is from [the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB#Trouble_Shooting). I created an `xorg.conf` file because no `50-marblemouse.conf` file existed.

Can anyone shed any new light on this issue?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You say it's a wireless mouse; this sounds like it could be a transmission issue.

I have had similar experiences with mine (Logitech M705) which were due to a metal plate that's part of my desk. The problem went away when I moved the receiver (with the help of an extension cord for the USB dongle).

Could this be the case for you as well? Would you try it and see if it makes a difference?

Other things that might affect transmission? Old batteries, microwave oven from the neighbour, big ole speaker set nearby, ...?